# Create a string with a string and a variable Swift4

Tags: swift

I'm trying to combine a string and a variable into a variable to use in a API request.

Here is the code I am using:

```
let urlString = ("example.com/api/balance/", addr)
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
```

The variable `urlString` needs to be set to `example.com/api/balance/addr`

Xcode 9 is giving me the error `Cannot convert value of type '(String, String)' to expected argument type 'String'`

How would I make the string and the variable into one string?

I am using Xcode 9 with Swift4

Comment: try this: `let urlString = "example.com/api/balance/" + "addr"`

Comment: addr is an variable so adding quotes to it won't work because it will turn it into a string.

Comment: yes but he said he wants the result to be `example.com/api/balance/addr` and what I posted returns that result. if addr is a variable of type string then it would be `let urlString = "example.com/api/balance/" + addr`

Comment: let urlString = "example.com/api/balance/\(addr)"

Comment: Please spend time reading the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book. Specifically, for this question, the section on [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)